# Не меняется стиль css

Tags: javascript

JS

```
document.getElementById('#pb').style.width = '20%';
```

html

```
 <div class="pb" id="pb"></div>
```

Почему не меняется CSS

Comment: jQuery портит новичков...

---

**P.S** Я про тех, кто программировать для браузера начинает сразу же с jQuery, часто, не разобравшись при этом с JS. Порой, некоторые jQuery`шики даже не подозревают, что в основе их фреймворка лежит JavaScript...

Comment: Да ну этот js, я php посмотрел, почитал статейки как и что делается, и через дня 2 -3 мог хоть что то написать. А с js, одни проблемы.

Comment: @NetSperes, поэтому у тебя возник такой неловкий вопрос..

Comment: Потому что js  мне не понятен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому, айдишник надо брать вот так

(без #)

document.getElementById('pb').style.width = '20%';

Comment: Интересно, какой гуру минуснул ответ?
Восстановили эквилибриум)

Comment: @dekameron я случайно, не со злости. Убрал. А вот принятие ответа не понятно. Мой вроде чуток поподробнее

Comment: @danpetruk: считайте это помощью начинающему автору ответа.

Comment: @VladD не влетело в голову, ну и ладно. Единственное, пусть админы сверят id АВ и АО. Просто накрутка тоже возможна)

Comment: Подскажите, а почему вот так не работает 
document.getElementById('pb').style.width = '10%';
sleep(2);
document.getElementById('pb').style.width = '30%';
sleep(15);
document.getElementById('pb').style.width = '35%';
sleep(10);
document.getElementById('pb').style.width = '55%';
sleep(20);
точнее работает, но только первое

Comment: @danpetruk, ну по поводу принятия - это не ко мне)

Answer (score 2):

Это не jquery. В jquery # == id. Здесь не нужно указывать #, так как есть другой эквивалент: getElementBy**Id**. Поэтому:

```
document.getElementById('pb').style.width = '20%';
```